# What stories include a story within the story that is brought to life, creating the main source of conflict? For example: Jumanji

Tags: creative-writing, plot

I'm outlining a new story idea and curious if there are other premises like it out there. I know there are, but am looking for more examples to make sure what I'm trying to do has not been done before. The main premise is a writer writes a fantasy novel, but upon finishing said novel, the evils from her book spill out into the real world. The writer and her friends must find a way to capture the evil back in the book.

I haven't spent much time working out the plotline or characters yet, but am curious; **What books, video games, tv shows, movies, etc. have a story within the story that is brought to life, creating the main source of conflict?**

The first thing that comes to mind is Jumanji, but I know there are others out there.

Comment: I blieve this question is off topic on this site. For one, it asks for a list of answers that are equally correct, which is not allowed on Stack Exchange sites. For another, it asks for book recommendations and not a solution to a writing problem, which is off topic on this site. Maybe ask your question at https://www.reddit.com/r/booksuggestions/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/suggestmeabook/?

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Goosebumps (2015) film's plot centers around the classic Children's Book Series from the 90s by R.L. Stine.   In the film, the original manuscripts of the books magically contain the monsters featured in the books contained and if opened, will cause them to manifest in the real world because R.L. Stine wrote the books on a magic typewriter that makes stories written by them come to life.  The plot kicks off when a friend of his daughter discovers the original manuscripts and accidentally unleashes a few of the monsters (with Slappy the Dummy, one of the series most infamous psychopathic villains, sneaking off to release all the monsters).  This was an unexpected direction for the film to take, as the Goosebumps series was an anthology series (with a few books being sequels to previous stories).  It's also interesting in that the books pre-date the film which added the lore.

Tron is another example where a video game programmer is transported inside of a computer and has to play in some of his games he created.  These games were marketed as part of the promotion.

Last Action Hero's plot is that a kid becomes transported into a Jack Slater Film, which is for all intents and purposes, a straight up 80s-90s action film staring Arnold Schwarzenegger.  The kid tries to convince Jack that it's a film and he's played by Arny but Jack doesn't bite (A clever gag occurs when the kid takes Jack to a Blockbuster to show him another film staring the actor, only to find in this Universe, Sylvester Stallone played the Terminator (the two have a friendly rivalry and make jokes about each other in their own films).).

There's an entire subgenre in anime with this as the core plot (the hero is brought to another world from his previous modern time).  In some cases this is a fictional world (often a fantasy video game world).

You might also look into works like "Who Framed Rodger Rabbit" where the "Rodger Rabbit & Baby Herman" cartoon is a fictional Golden Age Animated short but, in this universe, toons aren't ink and paint drawling's, but actual actors playing their characters in an otherwise realistic world.  Here, the story is around the Hollywood politics and scandal that allowed one of the Biggest Stars in Toon Town/Hollywood (In the world, Rodger is on Par with Bugs Bunny and Mickey Mouse in terms of A-List celebrity status) to be framed for the Murder of Marvin Acme, the genius behind the prop house supplying most of the props used in Toon films.  Here, the Cartoon celebs are treated as if they were Hollywood stars with similar problems (The detective working the case was instrumental in exonerating Goofy from spying charges and foiling the kidnappers of Huey, Dewey, and Louie, which seems to be this world's version of the Linberg Baby Kidnapping).